# Spring mvc mapping + displaytag pagination/sort

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, mapping, displaytag

I'm trying to use display tag library in my project.

JSP:

```
<display:table name="rooms" class="table table-striped" pagesize="5">
    <display:column property="name" titleKey="crs.admin.room.roomName" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="capacity" />
</display:table>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RoomController {
....
@RequestMapping(value = "/roomManagement*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("roomManagement");
    modelAndView.addObject("rooms", roomService.findAll());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

View resolver:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
              value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

When i opening page with it my link looks like:

```
http://localhost:8081/roomManagement
```

But after click on pagination/sort link it looks like:

```
http://localhost:8081/roomManagement.jsp?d-49653-s=0&d-49653-o=2
```

And becouse of ".jsp" suffix my controller doesnt handle this request, and doesnt put rooms list into view.
How should i handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it was really simple, ive added

```
 requestURI="/roomManagement"
```

parameter to display:table tag